# Makefile error while using struct (error: unknown type name ‘cmplx’)

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to make Makefile for multiple c files

Here is the Makefile :

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -lm
objects = N_1_Contg_FD_Ysparse.o Complex_Operations.o B_Calc_FD.o Excel_Input.o FDLoadFlow.o Matrix_Operations.o PI_Calc.o Ybus_Calc.o YbusLineAddEdit.o YbusLineRemoveEdit.o  
output: $(objects)
    $(CC) -g $(objects) -o output -lm
N_1_Contg_FD_Ysparse.o: N_1_Contg_FD_Ysparse.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c N_1_Contg_FD_Ysparse.c
Complex_Operations.o: Complex_Operations.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Complex_Operations.c
B_Calc_FD.o: B_Calc_FD.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c B_Calc_FD.c
Excel_Input.o: Excel_Input.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Excel_Input.c
FDLoadFlow.o: FDLoadFlow.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c FDLoadFlow.c
Matrix_Operations.o: Matrix_Operations.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Matrix_Operations.c
PI_Calc.o: PI_Calc.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c PI_Calc.c
Ybus_Calc.o: Ybus_Calc.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Ybus_Calc.c
YbusLineAddEdit.o: YbusLineAddEdit.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c YbusLineAddEdit.c
YbusLineRemoveEdit.o: YbusLineRemoveEdit.c Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c YbusLineRemoveEdit.c
```

So currently I am facing this error :

```
Ybus_Calc.c:17:15: error: unknown type name ‘cmplx’
   17 | void Ybuscalc(cmplx** Ytemp, float** linedata, int nbus, int lnsz)
```

It occurs when it is compiling at this point :

`gcc -Wall -lm -c Ybus_Calc.c`

Here is the header file included in N_1_Contg_FD_Ysparse.c (main function) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "Complex_Operations.c"
#include "Matrix_Operations.c"

#include "Excel_Input.c"
#include "Ybus_Calc.c"
#include "B_Calc_FD.c"
#include "FDLoadFlow.c"
#include "PI_Calc.c"
#include "YbusLineRemoveEdit.c"
#include "YbusLineAddEdit.c"



void datasize(char fl_name[], int* rw, int* clm);
void readcsvfile(float** dat, char fl_name[], int rw, int clm);
void Ybuscalc(cmplx** Ytemp, float** linedata, int nbus, int lnsz);
void B_Calc_Decoup(float** B1, float** B2, int nbus, int nload, float** loaddata, float** Ymag, float** tetha, float* V, float* delta);
void B_Calc_FD(float** B1, float** B2, int nbus, int nload, float** loaddata, float** Ymag, float** tetha);
void fastdecoupledanalysis(float** gendata, float** loaddata, int nbus, int ngen, int nload, float** Ymag, float** theta, float** B1, float** B2, float* V, float* delta, float* P, float* Q);
void PI_Calc(float** linedata, float** Y1mag, float** Tetha, float* V, float* delta, float* baseV,  int nbus, int lnsz, float** LORanking, int ir);
void YbusLineRemoveEdit(cmplx** Ytemp, cmplx element, int frm_bus, int to_bus, float** Ymag, float** tetha);
void YbusLineAddEdit(cmplx** Ytemp, cmplx element, int frm_bus, int to_bus, float** Ymag, float** tetha);
```

The structure is created in the Complex_Operations.c :

```
typedef struct cmplx
{
    float real;
    float imag;
}cmplx;
```

I am new to making Makefiles, if anyone can direct me what's really happening here it could really help. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that the cmplx type is defined in Complex_Operations.c. If you want that type to be available when compiling other files (like YBus_Calc.c), then the type needs to be declared in a file that's included in there.

I suspect that moving the type declaration from Complex_Operations.c to Complex_operations.h will address your immediate issue.

All this does raise the question of why the designer chose to make the type local to the .c file. Often that's done because that type is intended to be used only internally to the module and isn't part of the published API. Are you perhaps calling a function that isn't expected to be called from another module? Are you OK with that decision?

Comment: cmplx is used in most of the modules, I have tried to include it in the Modules_Declaration_Sparsity.h and remove from Complex_Operations.c, but it raises same errors in Complex_Operations.c

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your codebase, but you've shown that your problem is about where this type is declared. When you move the declaration, the error about the undefined type moves. The solutions you have available are to declare the struct in every .c file that needs it, or to declare the struct in a .h file that every .c files that needs it includes. I suggest moving it to a .h file and adding #include directives to make it work.

Comment: I have just tried declaring struct in every .c files, It gives me this `error : incompatible types when assigning to type ‘cmplx’ {aka ‘struct cmplx’} from type ‘int’` I am trying to debug why this is happening.

Comment: The incompatible type error means that you're assigning an integer to a variable that was declared as a struct cmplx. There should be a line number and file name with the error message that tells you exactly where the compiler is confused.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it accordingly. It works now. Thanks @Adam Bumpus !!!